# Spring fires AuthorizedEvent just before AuthorizationFailureEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying spring boot for some project and encountered an security related issue (possibly my mistake).

I want to log **user requests and operations in following manner** *(authentication is not a concern yet)*:

Log(User Request ) -> Log(User Authorization Status) ->

*if (authz is succeed) then*  {

- Log (Time of method invocation)
- Log (Finalization time of method execution)

}

To handle these I implemented one Filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractAuthorizationAuditListener
                          implements Filter {
    private ThreadLocal<Map> requestVariablesHolder= new ThreadLocal<>();
    public void doFilter(...) {
        String executedMethodName = getHandlerMethod().getMethod().getName();
        String executionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        HashMap<String,Object> params = ...

        this.requestVariablesHolder.set(params); 
        log("Request taken",requestVariablesHolder.get());
        chain.doFilter(...);
    }

  public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthorizationEvent e) {
       if (e instanceof AuthorizedEvent) { 
           log ("Authorization Granted", requestVariablesHolder.get());
       }else if (e instanceof AuthorizationFailureEvent) {
           log ("Authorization Failed", requestVariablesHolder.get());
       }
  }

}
```

and one HandlerInterceptor:

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public void preHandle () {
    log("started");
      }
      public void postHandle () {
            log("finished");
      }

}
```

For a user that has 'USER' role , I am able to take logs in the expected order. But for unauthorized user  (using mockMVC) logs are generated in following order:

1. Request Taken(with taskId : 9bf-....)
2. Authorization Granted (with taskId : 9bf-....)
3. Started (with taskId : 9bf-....)
4. Authorization Failed (with taskId : 9bf-....)

The unit test code block is as below:

```
@Test
public void testAuthForbidden() {
     initLogger(); 
     String token= obtainAccessToken("username","password");
     mockMvc.perform(put("/test").param("duration","100")
     .header("Authorization","Bearer "+token).andExpect(status()  
     .isForbidden()));

}
```

where controller method is

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
 @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
 public void putTest(...) {
 }
```

From the logs it is obvious that spring did not run the service method, but executed those implementations in an unexpected order **(and generates an AuthorizedEvent before AuthorizationFailureEvent although user does not have any 'USER' role)**.

I investigated code for AbstractSecurityInterceptor (FilterSecurityInterceptor) and find this causes the AuthorizedEvent triggering in "beforeInvocation", and then AuthorizationFailureEvent in "afterInvocation" method.

Is There a way to

1. not take AuthorizedEvent for unauthorized user
2. Run the implemented interceptor after FilterSecurityImplementor

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. No, 2. that is done IF the controller method is actually invoked it isn't because the security rules aren't matched.

Comment: M. Denium, thanks for reply; IF first one is 'No' as you replied, isn't this behavior somehow senseless? Why Spring rises an AuthorizedEvent although method is not authorized to be executed?

Comment: In addition, for second one , my aim was to handle in the way that you suggested. From the logs, I see that the MHandleInterceptor class is executed BEFORE the FilterSecurityInterceptor (thus generate a -'Started ... ' log- ), although 'security rules' aren't matched